# deserialize List<string> when being called from fetch...C#

Tags: c#, deserialization, asp.net-core-webapi

Web API 2.0 .Net 4.6.1

I have a web api method which accepts a list as a parameter:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod(List<string> mylist){
    // my code
   }
```

I call this function from the front end like so:

```
    fetch(MyMethodUrl+ "?mylist=ABC,123", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json"
        }
    })
```

When fetch calls my method, the mylist parameter is a list of 1:

```
     mylist[0] = "ABC,123"
```

Instead of this (which is what I want):

```
   mylist[0] = "ABC"
   mylist[1] = "123"
```

How do i format my string on the client side so my List will deserialize like i want it to? Thanks

Comment: I need to deserialize the string when the api method is called, not after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the query string to be

```
url?myList=ABC&myList=123
```

that's worked for me in the past